# Put my app on "pre-order" on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program, preorder

I'm making a game on iOS, and I'd like to know if it's possible to make a "pre-order" on my app.

> **Example :** I want to release my game on May. Is it possible to publish it on March but just for "pre-order" ?

It's a good way to see if the app is appealing or not.

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple inc. has strict guidelines for App submission and it review.
You can have a look at this.

You requirement for pre-order app submission violates oint 2.9: `Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected.`

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) will give you more insight on the process.

So you have to either cut-short the game of yours and submit it as full-functional app. Apple doesn't care how much level your game has. And in later on-releases you can add the levels and updates. But make sure you adhere with the guidelines and do not display the "demo/trial/etc".

Comment: Do free versions of apps count for demo or trial?

Comment: No free apps are not counted as demo. There are hundreds of free apps in app store.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS app store has no such functionality. You can only make it available or not, there is no "pre-order" status.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's like "demo", "beta" policy and so on. You cannot do this in AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.
You can only release apps that are fully functional.
That's why you can't release beta apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you want to "test the waters" and/or build "hype" best thing you can do is create a landing page website with a good app description/image and see how many people are willing to leave their emails on your entry form.

Then on launch day you email blast those people.

Answer (score 1):

If the app doesn't work or look like a beta, you don't have to call it a beta in the description sent to Apple.  If your app is complete and good enough for Apple to approve it after it's submitted, you still don't have to release it immediately.  When in the approved but unreleased state, you might be able to use up to 50 iTunes redemption codes to allow further reviewing of your app.

Before you can update the unreleased app, you might have to release it for a couple hours at 3AM in only Monte Carlo or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like TestFlight to release a Beta to a limited number of people (I think you can release to a max of 1000 with TestFlight)

More information on TestFlight here - http://www.testflightapp.com/